# How to filter documents from map based on 2 values and create another map

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I am not much familiar with the java 8 syntax and its stream API, And trying to achieve some complex filtering on map of map.

Below is my code using the traditional map looping and filtering.

```
public class HashMapFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

        Map<String,String> foo = new HashMap<>();
        foo.put("lang", "en");
        foo.put("type", "msg");
        foo.put("location", "usa");
        map.put("1", foo);

        Map<String,String> bar = new HashMap<>();
        bar.put("lang", "en");
        bar.put("type", "user");
        bar.put("location", "usa");
        map.put("2", bar);

        Map<String,String> baz = new HashMap<>();
        baz.put("lang", "en");
        baz.put("type", "msg");
        baz.put("location", "usa");
        map.put("3", baz);

        HashMap<String, Map<String, String>> filteredMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, String> innerMap = entry.getValue();
            if(innerMap.get("lang").equals("en") && innerMap.get("type").equals("msg")) {
                filteredMap.put(entry.getKey(),innerMap);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Size of filtered map : "+ filteredMap.size());
    }
}
```

As you can see I just want to filter the inner maps on the basis of `lang` and `type` but code using the traditional way is quite complex and I am sure, it can easily be rewritten using the java 8 stream API.
Note: As illustrated in my example after the filtered map would contains only 2 inner map, as there is only 2 maps which has both `lang=en` and `type=msg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost same just add that condition in `filter` and then use `Collectors.toMap` for collecting into `Map`

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> filteredMap = map.entrySet()
                                                  .stream()
                                                  .filter(entry->entry.getValue().get("lang").equals("en") && entry.getValue().get("type").equals("msg"))
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```